# CI Pipeline that doesn't require OAuth?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, deployment, continuous-integration

I am wanting to build a CI/CD pipeline Github app. What CI tool can I use to leverage to build this?

I want my application to handle the Github OAuth so as far as the user is concerned, they only connect to their Github but behind the scenes, I run Pipelines through Jenkins, CircleCI, AWS Codepipelines or something similar.

These all require the user authorise these Apps via their own OAuth but I'm hoping for a solution where I can pass an existing access token or clone a repo and send the CI tool the code to then execute the Pipeline on.

Does anybody know of any CI/CD tools that work via providing a Github access token or sending a clone of the code from Github to or would I have to look at rolling my own CI tool for something like this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correct you just need to add Github personal api token to jenkins credentials as 'username and password'. You can use it in your pipelines.

Also I leave some useful links for you:

- [GitHub Permissions and API token Scopes for Jenkins](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/234710368-GitHub-Permissions-and-API-token-Scopes-for-Jenkins)
- [Github branch source plugin](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/cloud-admin-guide/github-branch-source-plugin) - which will automate job creation on jenkins side and will create webhooks on github side.
- [Youtube channel of Cloudbees](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDmeeVDrp0o) - this video is about configuring Github branch source.